# Tomcat 100% CPU and no response from apps - debugging options

Tags: tomcat

we run Tomcat7 on Windows with two apps.
Occasionally the Server gets up to 100% CPU utilization and freezes. All apps stop responding.
This also goes for apps like PSI Probe, which freeze together with the rest.

What options do I have to find out which app (and later which function) cause this – even when the tomcat itself stops responding? (I have no option on changing the app code – it’s developed by a 3rd party)

Comment: The problem could be that Tomcat has a memory problem (either you have allocated it too few memory or one of the apps has a serious memory problem) and is constantly running the garbage collector. You can activate GC logging via the CATALINA_OPTS. Add `-Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat7/gc.log` or a similar option. The GC should run more often then every few seconds and even a full run shouldn't take longer than 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a try. Do you really mean "GC should run more often then every few seconds" or do you mean should NOT run more than every few seconds?

Comment: You're right: "should not" is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the GC log. It is indeed a memory problem. Do you know if/how I can log memory usage per application?

Comment: I don't think you can. They all run it the same VM and cannot be properly separated. Can't you run them in separate Tomcat instance for a test?

Comment: That's what I'll have to do then. Thanks again for the support.